# Use a CSV to create a SQL table

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I have a csv file with the following format:

```
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Description  | brand1 | brand2 | brand3 |
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+
| afkjdjfkafj  |      1 |      0 |      0 |
| fhajdfhjafh  |      1 |      0 |      0 |
| afdkjfkajljf |      0 |      1 |      0 |
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to write a python script that reads the csv and create a table in sql. I want the table to have the description and the derived brand. If there is a one in the brand name column of the csv then the description is associated with that brand. I want to then create a sql table with the description and the associated brand name.

The table will be :

```
+-------------+---------------+
| Description | derived brand |
+-------------+---------------+
| afkjdjfkafj | brand 1       |
+-------------+---------------+
```

So far I have written the code for reading the csv and made the descriptions a list.

```
df = pd.read_csv(SOURCE_FILE, delimiter=",")
descriptions = df['descriptions'].tolist()
```

Please provide some guidance on how to read the file and achieve this because I am so lost. Thanks!

Comment: Must you use python? SQL Server can use `BULK INSERT` and `OPENROWSET` to import this directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a csv file into SQL Server database using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257899/writing-a-csv-file-into-sql-server-database-using-python)

Comment: @scsimon no there is not need to use python but I am not sure how to do so in sql because it is a csv file

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221805/how-to-set-the-first-row-of-csv-data-as-column-name-in-sql-server), but here's the basics

Create your table...

```
create table myStagingTable (Description varchar(64), Brand1 bit, Brand2 bit, Brand3 bit)
```

Then, bulk insert into it but ignore the first row, if your first row has column headers.

```
bulk insert myStagingTable
   from 'C:\somefile.csv',
   with( firstrow = 2,
         fieldterminator = ',',
         rowterminator = '\n')
```

Now your data will be in a table just like it is in your excel file.To insert it into your final table, you can use `IIF` and `COALESCE`

```
insert into finalTable
select distinct
    [Description]
    ,DerivedBrand = coalesce(iif(Brand1 = 1,'Brand1',null),iif(Brand2 = 1,'Brand2',null),iif(Brand3 = 1,'Brand3',null))
from myStagingTable
```

**[See a DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24db7a5085540ced0fa36d250d816f24)**

Comment: Thanks! But can I associate the description and the brand? Because it is important for me to only have two columns in the final table. I need to be able to associate the description and find where there is a 1 in the brand columns and then add that as the derived brand to the final table. Is that something I can do in SQL?