# Django data storage - SQL or something else?

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I am building a Django web app which will essentially serve static data to the users. By static, I mean that admins will be able to upload new datasets but no data entries will be made by users. Effectively, once the data is uploaded, it will be read-only on request by a user.

Given that these are quite large datasets (200k+ rows), I figured that SQL would be the best way to store the data - this avoids reading large datasets into memory (as you'd have to with a pickle or json?). This has the added bonus of using Django models to access the data.

However, I am not sure of the best way to do this, or if there is a better alternative to SQL. I currently have an admin page that allows you to upload .xlsx files which are then parsed and added as model entries row-by-row. It takes FOREVER (30+ minutes for 100K rows). Perhaps I should be creating a whole new db outside of Django and then importing that somehow, but I can't find much documentation on how this could/should be done. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for any wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `.csv` file format instead of `.xlsx`. Python has libraries that allow you to easily write to an sql database using `.csv` format (comma separated value). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261532/7070685) answer could be of further assistance. I hope you find what you're looking for and happy coding!

Comment: I've been looking into an option like this. I'll follow the post you've linked, thanks!

Comment: @CameronHyde if you think this is the answer please mark it as the correct one. I'm happy I could help.